# GPU timing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, gpu

I am using a GeForce GT 720 to do some basic calculations in Matlab.

I am simply doing matrix multiplication:

```
A = rand(3000,3000);     % Define array using CPU
tic;                     % Start clock
Agpu = gpuArray(A);      % Transfer data to GPU
Bgpu = Agpu*Agpu;        % Perform computation on GPU
time = toc;              % Stop clock
```

In this code, my clock is timing the data transfer to the GPU and matrix multiplication on the GPU, and I get time ~ 4 seconds. I suspect that the data transfer is taking much more time than the multiplication, so I isolate it with my timer:

```
A = rand(3000,3000);     % Define array using CPU
tic;                     % Start clock
Agpu = gpuArray(A);      % Transfer data to GPU
time = toc;              % Stop clock
Bgpu = Agpu*Agpu;        % Perform computation on GPU
```

and indeed it takes ~ 4 seconds. However, if I comment the last line of the code, so that no multiplicaiton is done, my code speeds up to ~0.02 seconds.

Does performing a computation with the GPU *after* transferring data to the GPU alter the speed of the data transfer?

Comment: When commenting the multiplication, I suspect that this weird result is produced because the bytecode optimization sees no usage for the declared array `Agpu` and doesn't even perform the transfer... it's just an hypotesis, but I cannot verify it because my graphic card doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this behaviour at all (R2017b, Tesla K20c) - for me, either way, the transfer takes 0.012 seconds. Note that if you're running this in a fresh MATLAB session each time, the very first time you run anything at all on the GPU takes a few seconds - perhaps that accounts for the 4 seconds?

In general, use [`gputimeit`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gputimeit.html) to time stuff on the GPU to ensure you don't see strange results from the asynchronous nature of some GPU operations.